# how to emulate a real external sd (update: removable storage) card in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I try to emulate a external sdcard as it would be in a real device.

In a real device the external sdcard is not writeable except you use the new "Storage Access Framework" (API 21 & 22)

When I add an sdcard either with a file or Size ...

[image]

I always get a writeable sdcard, which is not true with a real device (I guess). I could create the Folder "CreateFolder" with just ( I know, I should not use the direct access, but this is only for a test to see if I have write access):

```
        String spathWriteTest="/storage/sdcard/";
        new File(spathWriteTest + "createFolder").mkdir();
```

[image]

Any Idea, howto emulate a real external sdcard ?

Comment: The access rules will depend on if the sd card is a primary or secondary external storage.  On an emulator or other device with nothing else, it will be the primary.  You want to explore the behavior where it is secondary.  I don't know that the emulator supports that without code-level modifications.  You might consider creating something else which exposes documents in a similar manner to test against.  Also, I believe you can use the more abstract API for the primary storage as well - even though you can also access it directly, so it is really only the decisioning logic you can't test.

Comment: Thanks Chris. In the end I would like to simulate the write access which is granted with the new external storage features from API 21 & 22. I would like to test the new Intent "ACTION OPEN DOCUMENT TREE" to persist the write access to a specific folder, but for that I need a nonwritable external storage as prerequisite. I could buy a new device with lollipop on it with externalstorage slot, but I think this should be possible to emulate.

Comment: I believe you will find that you can use "ACTION OPEN DOCUMENT TREE" for the primary external storage of the emulator, as well as a hypothetical secondary ones.  You will merely have to write your program to only use that and the resulting abstract access mechanisms, and not "cheat" by doing direct access to literal files.

Comment: ok. thanks. But I can't simulate a readonlyaccess to a folder and after using the Intent to persist writeaccess to check the writeacess after a reboot of the avd, right ?

Comment: Easy answer would be to see what happens if you do not attempt to persist it.

Comment: of course this will work in the emulator, because I have write access. But the goal of emulating is to emulate a real device. I guess I am confused with the termology, which CommonsWare explained. I like to emulate a "removable storage" and not a "external stoage".

Comment: Again, if you want to test this, do not use direct File access even though the emulator would permit that.  Instead, use the abstract APIs that you are trying to test.

Comment: I know, that I should not use the direct access, this is only for a test. Abstract API is working in the emulator. I knewed that before asking. But it works also with direct access. I would like to have an environment, where directs access is prohibited, but permitted by the abstract API.

Comment: You are free to build a customized emulator from sources.  Or you could simply configure your program to *always* use the abstract API, or at least *test* such a configuration of it.

Comment: Ok. build a customized emulator :-) ? No thanks. If no one knows howto do with an already existing emulator, I guess my solution will be just buying a device with lollipop and external storage. thanks for helping

Comment: You have been told several times how to test this with the existing emulator, by merely confining yourself to the APIs that would work in all cases, but seem to dislike that practical solution.

Comment: No need to tell howto test. This is not the question. The question is "howto emulate a removable storage". Meanwhile I accepted the answer of CommonsWare, who explained this in simple words. He also mentions genymotion, which is a good hint regarding the question. I hope you are not upset about the long chats with me. I changed my loginname and picture, so I am more recognizable for future questions  :-) Have a good time.

Comment: Up-voted the Q.   It's a pity we don't have a straightforward method to test this usage pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set up an AVD, and it refers to an "SD card", it is really referring to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). The emulator does not emulate removable storage. You could see if Genymotion emulates removable storage.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So this is a termology confusion, that I made. I read your referenced articles. Thanks very interesting. Idon't know if I understood correct . Does getExternalFilesDirs() also return a path to a removable storage ?

Comment: I already checked Genymotion and I didn't find any removable storage. But of course I didn't check all available builds.

Comment: @user1344545: "Does getExternalFilesDirs() also return a path to a removable storage ?" -- on Android 4.4 and higher, if that method returns 2+ entries, the second and subsequent entries should be on removable storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's correct, and you should call `isExternalStorageRemovable( File )` on each one to confirm if it's actually removable or not. This was added in Android 5.0 (API 21) (LOLLIPOP).